# In company of thieves

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

What am I?

> With thieves I consort,
> With the Vilest, in short,
> I'm quite at ease in depravity,
> Yet all divines use me,
> And savants can't lose me,
> For I am the centre of gravity.

Comment: Is this an original riddle?

Comment: Well, it is not made by me. But our friend group helped me to make this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer must be

> The letter **v**

Reasoning

> It's found in each of the words "thieves", "Vilest", "depravity", "divines", "savants" and "gravity" with the wordplay in each line subtly indicating that each word contains the letter.

Last line

> 'v' is the centre letter of the word gra**v**ity.